# References to boost::smart_ptr pointed to object and checking their validity

Tags: c++, boost, reference, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Given the following:

```
class Curve {
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Curve> Pointer;
  // ...
private:
  // ...
};

class CurveShift: public Curve {
public:
  CurveShift(const Curve & curve);
  // ...
private:
  const Curve & curve_;
  // ...
};
```

I was wondering whether there is a consensus best practice to use when you want to do something like:

```
Curve::Pointer pointer(new Curve());
SomeGlobalRepository::Add("key", pointer);
```

And in some other place you have:

```
CurveShift cs(*SomeGlobalRepository::Get("key"));
```

You don't really have any assurance that `SomeGlobalRepository` will contain the original `Curve::Pointer` when `CurveShift` will need it, and hence `curve_` might point to deallocated memory, or even memory that was already reallocated to something else. I believe that one possible solution would be for `CurveShift` to use a `boost:weak_ptr<Curve>` instead of a `const Curve &`, but I am pretty certain that would mean that you can't use `Curve` on the stack anymore, and any instance would have to go on the heap (with the constructors becoming private and the objects being created through a factory). Is there a better strategy to achieve the desired behavior? My gut feeling is that while in theory this could be a serious problem, practical use cases would not lend themselves to creating these tricky situations.

Comment: Why not have `CurveShift` hold a `shared_ptr<Curve>` itself?  That is sort of what the "shared" is all about...

Comment: Does the network of curves contain cycles, or not? If not then everything should be `shared_ptr`. And I don't see how there sensibly can be cycles, since `CurveShift` holds a reference, so a `CurveShift` can only reference a `Curve` that was created before it. A `CurveShift` could reference itself, to create a cycle, but that doesn't seem very sensible...

Comment: If the curve to be shifted is allocated on the stack, how do I get a shared_ptr to it?

Comment: If the curve to be shifted is on the stack, how are you planning to ensure that it still exists when the `CurveShift` is used? If you have a way of doing that, then you can create a `shared_ptr` with a deleter that does nothing, pointing to the stack object. If you don't have a way of doing that, then you simply need dynamic allocation, that's what it's for. Perhaps you could dynamically allocate a copy when you create the `CurveShift`, thus allowing you to use `Curve` on the stack when appropriate, but not when not. Copying polymorphically is a little tricksy, mind.

Comment: `shared_ptr<Curve>` objects can be stored in STL containers. The problem that I am trying to solve elegantly is that you could have a `CurveShift` that references a `shared_ptr<Curve>` in a container, and the object in the container could be deallocated before the `CurveShift` is deallocated, rendering the `const Curve &` in the `CurveShift` invalid.

Comment: @Hazerider ... pass a copy of the `shared_ptr<Curve>` into your `CurveShift` object ... then the memory won't be deallocated when the container is destroyed since your `CurveShift` object will still have a valid handle on the `shared_ptr` ... basically a `shared_ptr` is doing reference-counting, so it won't destroy the memory pointer it's managing until there are no more references to the object on the heap.  You can reference my answer for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in your comments that you have an object allocated on the stack that you want a `std::shared_ptr` to ... if that is the case, you'll have to copy your object from the stack into the heap doing something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<my_object_t> sh_ptr(new my_object_t(stack_object));
```

That will then allocate a copy of your stack-object on the heap and created a `std::shared_ptr` from that heap-allocated object.  You can then copy your newly created shared pointer into a container, etc.

Also I would concur with Nemo's comments that you should have your class `CurveShift` hold a copy of the `shared_ptr` rather than a constant reference to a `Curve` class object ... that way the `shared_ptr` object will control the life-time of the pointer reference, and should a container or some other object try to destroy the memory pointed to by the `shared_ptr` instance during it's own deconstruction, the memory reference will still be maintained in the `CurveShift` instance since calling the destructor of the `shared_ptr` elsewhere will not actually deallocate the memory for the object on the heap as your `CurveShift` instance object has an active reference to that heap allocated object held by the `shared_ptr`.  By holding just a constant reference, you remove the whole advantage of using a `shared_ptr` type which is controlled deconstruction of an object allocated on the heap through some form of reference-counting.

In the end, I would write you class like:

```
class CurveShift: public Curve {
public:
  CurveShift(const shared_ptr<Curve>& ptr): _curve(ptr)
  {
      // ... rest of constructor
  }

private:
  shared_ptr<Curve> curve_; //will remain valid for lifetime of CurveShift instance
  // ...
};
```

And then you would make a call like:

```
CurveShift cs(SomeGlobalRepository::Get("key"));
```

Which copies in the `shared_ptr` to your `CurveShift` instance and increases the reference count to the pointer on the heap its managing.

Comment: +1 -- for your first code snippet though I would recommend `std::make_shared` instead. One should not create unnamed `shared_ptr` that way because it can lead to memory leaks if an exception is thrown and the compiler is unfavorable to you in how it orders the calls.

Comment: See Scott Meyers' Effective C++ Item #17: Store newed objects in smart pointers in standalone statements.

Comment: @Jason: Lol -- You don't have to do both. If you give the variable a name `make_shared` stops being a necessity. (Though some might call it more readable). (This works because the "standalone statement" exists inside the implementation of `make_shared`, so you know that this loophole gets closed)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Sorry, I got confused ... re-reading your comments I now realize you were saying to use `std::make_shared` instead of declaring an unnamed shared pointer, not use `std::make_shared` and a copy-constructor. +1 on your answer for being so patient with me (in addition to it being a good answer as well) :-)

Comment: While this is a perfectly valid solution, I wanted to avoid making copies of the underlying `Curve`. I wanted to have a framework where the `CurveShift` objects would be able to keep track of the lifetime of the underlying `Curve`, and throw an error when you try to use a `CurveShift` for which the underlying `Curve` isn't valid anymore.

Comment: From my understanding of how this would work, you aren't making any copies of the underlying `Curve` object ... you're just making a light-weight copy of a *pointer* to the underlying `Curve` object.  With the `shared_ptr` idiom there is also no need to throw an error in a `CurveShift` object because the pointer will only go invalid when there are no more references to the `Curve` object, which would mean the destruction of all containers and associated `CurveShift` objects pointing to the allocated `Curve` object.  Is there some extra information I'm missing that makes this not work?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `shared_ptr`, the object will be maintained as valid. The raw reference of course is not always going to be valid. Why not just make `curve_` a `shared_ptr`? `weak_ptr` is designed to break cycles. I don't see any cycles here, so there should be no reason for it.

(I think there's something constraining your design here that's missing from your question)